# Arrow function is not a function

Tags: javascript

I'm getting the error `TypeError: f is not a function` for the following: What am I doing wrong?

```
var expressws = require("express");
var appws = expressws();
var expressWs = require('express-ws')(appws);

function x(ws)
{
    console.log("send");
}

function loop(f,t)
{
    setTimeout(() => loop(), t);
    f();
}

appws.ws('/', function(ws, req) {
    ws.on('message', function(msg){
        var data = JSON.parse(msg);
        if(data.action == "Logged in"){
            loop(() => x(ws),1000);
        }
    });
```

});

Comment: You are calling a function which is not present in the code . In this line. `function loop(f,t){ setTimeout(() => loop(), t);f();}`.

Comment: `setTimeout(() => { loop(f,t); }, t);`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following indirect recursive call passes nothing as an argument to `loop`, hence the error.

```
setTimeout(() => loop(/* should pass two arguments here */), t);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass arguments into loop function

`setTimeout(() => loop(f, t), t);`

another approach is

`setTimeout(loop.bind(null, f, t), t);`

or lodash version

`_.delay(loop, t, f, t);`